# it is the fact that the google map does not always line up well in the iframed area?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

What are other ways to embed Google maps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use the [Google Maps API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/). It will render in a `<div>`, as in the following example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head> 
   <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/> 
   <title>Google Maps Basic Demo</title> 
   <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;sensor=false" 
           type="text/javascript"></script> 
</head> 
<body onunload="GUnload()"> 

   <div id="map" style="width: 400px; height: 300px"></div> 

   <script type="text/javascript"> 

   if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
      var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));

      map.setUIToDefault();
      map.setCenter(new GLatLng(39.00, -77.00), 5);
   }
   </script> 
</body> 
</html>
```

[image: Basig Map example]

Comment: What are benefits to use any jquery plugin related to Maps inplace of Google Map's default Iframe code?

Comment: Using a jquery plugin may make it easier to implement, but in most cases there is no significant benefit. The Google Maps API already comes with a set of cross-brower methods that you can easily call from JavaScript directly, as in the example above.

Comment: If i use google api http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;sensor=false" will it create maps faster than <Iframe> method? What is the best method to add google Map in webpage to get good speed in loading of map then using the map using buttons

Comment: @jitendra: Can you give us a more detailed example of the iframe method that you are using?

Comment: in Iframed maps some times the red bulb not coming up, sometimes white bubble not coming up or not positioned proerly